Accented characters in Presidio deny list not being recognized despite correct YAML encoding
I'm using Microsoft Presidio for text analysis and anonymization, and I have a configuration file (all-config.yml) to specify recognizers, including some deny lists with accented characters. However, I am facing an issue where accented words in the deny list are not being matched in the text, despite ensuring that the YAML file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.
Here's an example of my setup:
from presidio_analyzer import AnalyzerEngineProvider
from presidio_anonymizer import AnonymizerEngine

FR_TEXT = """Nom complet : Jean Dupont  
Préférence sexuelle : Jean s'identifie comme hétérosexuel"""

analyzer_conf_file = "path/to/all-config.yml"

provider = AnalyzerEngineProvider(analyzer_engine_conf_file=analyzer_conf_file)
analyzer = provider.create_engine()

analyzer_results = analyzer.analyze(text=FR_TEXT, language="fr")
anonymizer = AnonymizerEngine()
result = anonymizer.anonymize(text=FR_TEXT, analyzer_results=analyzer_results)

print(result.text)

YAML Configuration (all-config.yml):
supported_languages: 
- en
- fr
- nl

default_score_threshold: 0

nlp_configuration:
  nlp_engine_name: spacy
  models:
  -
    lang_code: en
    model_name: en_core_web_lg
  -
    lang_code: fr
    model_name: fr_core_news_lg
  -
    lang_code: nl
    model_name: nl_core_news_lg

recognizer_registry:
  global_regex_flags: 26

  recognizers: 
  - name: "SexualityFr"
    supported_language: "fr"
    supported_entity: "SEXUALITY"
    deny_list: [hétérosexuel]
    deny_list_score: 1

Expected Output:
The word "hétérosexuel" should be anonymized, but it is not being recognized.


The encoding used by Python might depend on the platform. Can you verify that the YAML file and any other input is actually read as UTF-8?

Indeed, `import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())outputscp1252. I have modified internal method in analyzer_engine_provider.py to from yaml.safe_load(open(default_conf_file,)'to'yaml.safe_load(open(default_conf_file,encodig='utf-8'). Yet, would there be cleaner way to set global setting from cp1252toutf-8`?

The officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been .yaml since at least September 2006. YML is a different (and older) format derived from XML.

The solution I always warmly recommend is to remove Windows from your life. If you can't do that yet, there are multiple ways to attempt to approximate sanity for this particular problem; the simplest for this scenario is probably to set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 in your environment. There are many, many existing questions about solving Python encoding problems on Windows.
